# How to retrieve @@SPID from running stored procedure called from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, raiserror

I am trying to implement "cancel" functionality on pages with potentially long running select queries or processes. Indexing and other optimizations have been done to minimize this possibility, but during higher server load times some waiting on complex processes is still possible.

When a process has started, a modal busy spinner is displayed with a Cancel button. If the user chooses to stop the process, I want to use the following steps:

I have a test stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SpID varchar(10) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @@SPID);
    RAISERROR(99999, 10, 1, @SpID) WITH NOWAIT;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'
END
```

The idea is to accomplish the following...

1. In the called stored procedure, get the assigned `SPID` from `@@SPID`
2. Use the `RAISERROR` statement to create a non-error condition message containing the `SPID`
3. While the `WAITFOR` delay is running, the application function that called the stored procedure retrieves the message with the `SPID`
4. Send the `SPID` to another stored procedure to kill that process (*KILL will take care of closing the connection and rolling back the data action(s)*)

My understanding so far is that the message from this setup can be picked up by the calling ASP.NET C# code, but I can't find an example that will retrieve the message while still allowing the calling code to continue (with `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar`).

```
/* CommentTest Procedure */
CREATE PROCEDURE CommentTest
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SpID varchar(10) = CONVERT(varchar(10), @@SPID);
    RAISERROR(99999, 10, 1, @SpID) WITH NOWAIT;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
END
```

```
private string _spID;

private string RunCommentTestWaitForSP()
{
   _spID = "";

   try
   {
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
      {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CommentTest", conn))
         {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
               conn.Open();
            }

            // this is where I'm stuck...
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _spID = "The message returned from RAISERROR...";
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      log.Error("RunCommentTestWaitForSP exception: " + ex.ToString() + " / " + ex.Message);
      log.Error("RunCommentTestWaitForSP stack trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
   }

   return spID;
}

private void LinkButtonCancelProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunCommentTestWaitForSP();
    if (_spID.Length > 0 && "IsNumeric") {
        "call function to run sp_KillSpID"
    }
}
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_KillSpID]
    @SpID varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @KillStatement varchar(10) = 'KILL ' + @SpID;
    EXEC(@KillStatement);
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Good point - using that prefix is a bad habit that began when I joined my current team. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the [`InfoMessage` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) on the SqlConnection object:

```
private string RunCommentTestWaitForSP()
{
    try 
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CommentTest", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
            conn.InfoMessage += ReceiveSQLInfo;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      log.Error($"RunCommentTestWaitForSP exception: {ex} / {ex.Message}");
      log.Error($"RunCommentTestWaitForSP stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
   }
}

private void ReceiveSQLInfo(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    //sender will be the "conn" connection above
    var spID = e.Message;
  
    // Here you could open a new connection 
    //   (we expect the existing connection is still busy)
    //    and use it to kill the spID
}
```

Just keep in mind the `ExecuteNonQuery()` function won't finish until the stored procedure does, which is not until *after* the `WAIT FOR DELAY` code is also finished. Therefore the `LinkButtonCancelProcess_Click()` method also won't do what you expect, since the `if()` block is not reached until after the stored procedure is finished anyway.

Additionally, depending on how the C# `RunCommentTestWaitForSP()` is called, the computer may not be able to process any event messages until it finishes.

Comment: This is helpful to understand, I was wondering if the relationship between the called SP and calling code had an asynchronous hook when using RAISERROR. Perhaps I need to take a different track from inside the cancel button code and call sp_who to retrieve a list and (somehow) identify which process is mine to kill.

Comment: Note that `// we expect the existing connection is still busy` is also potentially very dangerous. SQL Server takes no special precautions to ensure SPIDs are not reused quickly, so if the timing goes wrong, and depending on the rights of your account, you may end up killing an innocent process. @fourells5: consider exposing the `SqlCommand` instance and calling `.Cancel()` on it (this can be done from a different thread). This still potentially includes synchronization issues, but at least those are fixable. `.Cancel()` is not guaranteed to work quickly, but then neither is `KILL`.